# Multi-Lingual Places API

Tags: parameters, places, google-places-api

I'm developing a website and I'm looking for a places api (that isn't google!) 
one which can take a place parameter in any (or most) languages and return me values both in the language I've sent the request in, and in english accompanied by its coordinates.

Only one i'm familiar with right now is the google places api though I can't use it for legal reasons, they don't allow using that api unless its accompanied with their maps, and I'm using mapbox for this project, so no google places api for me.

any good known api that can deliver me both accurate info and is multi lingual ?

Comment: Which Languages/Countries do you need to support?

Comment: Israel/Hebrew and english mostly.